# Google analytics Core reporting v 3 - how to get the base url

Tags: c#, google-analytics, reporting, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get  the base url for Google analytics and for some reason i can't get it to work - I have tried the following:

```
                //this is the old url and did use to work ( see   `//https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/ )`
    //const string baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";

                // this is also outdated 
//const string baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data";

               // this doesnt  seem to work!!! 
const string baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data";
```

here is a bit of the code i have written which should build the url

```
  const string baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/";

                var retailers = affiliateRetailerRepository.GetAffiliateRetailerByScheme(affiliateScheme.Id);
                foreach (var affiliateRetailer in retailers)
                {
                    var query = new DataQuery(baseUrl)
                                    {
                                        Ids = affiliateRetailer.Code,
                                        //todo - custom var may neeed to be put back Dimensions = "ga:customVarName(n),transactionId,ga:productName,ga:productSku,ga:date,ga:hour",
                                        Dimensions = "transactionId,ga:productName,ga:productSku,ga:date,ga:hour",
                                        //Metrics = "ga:itemRevenue,ga:revenuePerItem,ga:itemQuantity",
                                        Metrics = "ga:itemRevenue,ga:itemQuantity",
                                        Segment = "gaid::-8",
                                        Filters = filters,
                                        GAStartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                        GAEndDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                        NumberToRetrieve = 10000
                                    };
                    Uri url = query.Uri;
```

Using the above i get the following http:

{https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/?max-results=10000&dimensions=transactionId,ga:productName,ga:productSku,ga:date,ga:hour&end-date=2012-08-28&filters=ga:source=@where-to-buy.co,ga:source=@where-to-purchase.us,ga:source=@where-to-buy.fr,ga:source=@wheretopurchase.de,ga:source=@where-to-buy.es,ga:source=@wheretopurchase.it,ga:source=@where-to-purchase.ru,ga:source=@where-to-buy.pl,ga:source=@where-to-buy.se,ga:source=@where-to-buy.nl,ga:source=@where-to-purchase.us,ga:source=@wheretopurchase.ca&ids=ga:57437629&metrics=ga:itemRevenue,ga:itemQuantity&start-date=2012-03-13&segment=gaid::-8}

I know that i have code rot as i haven't looked at this piece of code for quite a while but if anyone has any suggestions - i thought it would be simply changing the base url to the most up to date one but that does not seem to work.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Or just if someone has a working url which i could use to build mine that would also be useful as i mentioned this was put together a while ago so it might mean i need to reformat the whole code in line with the new API format so seeing one which works would be useful then i can tailor it to my needs.
Thanks

Comment: For reference, here's a github commit that updated the url in the python library I am using: https://github.com/jsma/python-googleanalytics/commit/6be9b5ff8d6f353154ac556e16eafca130ab3d3e. It looks like this is the step you're trying to make. I upgraded to v2.4, which still works for me.

Comment: thankyou - it was as simple as i missed out a ga: before the transactionId then 2.4 worked for me aswel!!